# For integer $n \ge 3$, is $3^{2^{n-3}} -1 \equiv 0 \pmod {2^n}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction, exponentiation

For integer $n \ge 3$, is $3^{2^{n-2}} -1 \equiv 0 \pmod {2^n}$

Here's what I am seeing:

$$3^{2} - 1 = 2^3$$
$$3^{4} - 1 = 5\times2^4$$
$$3^{8} - 1 = 205\times2^5$$
$$3^{16} - 1 = 672,605\times2^6$$

I was trying to prove that this is true for all $n \ge 3$ but I am not clear how to do it.

How would one establish the inductive step?

Comment: Thanks, @JohnOmielan  I didn't realize it generalized to all odd integers.  Cool.

Comment: You're welcome. Note another duplicate one is [How to prove that $a^{2^{n-2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/587416/602049), but it's more abstract & complicated than what you need, and possibly want, for your question here.

Comment: Note when determining the divisibility of an expression, a key thing to check on is if the expression can be factored. With your question, note the difference of squares means $3^{2^{k-1}} - 1 = \left(3^{2^{k-2}} - 1\right)\left(3^{2^{k-2}} + 1\right)$. Since $3^{2^{k-2}} + 1$ is even, then $2 \mid 3^{2^{k-2}} + 1$. Thus, if $2^{k} \mid 3^{2^{k-2}} - 1$, then $2^{k+1} \mid 3^{2^{k-1}} - 1$. Note this inductive step also applies if $3$ is replaced by any odd $a$, with the base case due to $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ also always being true.